# Derivative of a vector with respect to a matrix with quadratic term

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have the following function $u : \mathbb{R}^{n\times m} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{n}$
given by
$$u = Q(a-Q^{\top} \mathbb{1}) = Qa-Q Q^{\top} \mathbb{1} $$

where $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}, a \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $\mathbb{1}$ is a vector of all ones with dimension $n$.

I am interested in computing $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial Q}$$ but do not have many ideas. I know it should be $\frac{\partial Qa}{\partial Q} = a \otimes I_n$ but what about the quadratic term?

Comment: How is $\frac{\partial Qa}{\partial Q} = a \otimes I_m$? That does not correspond to the linear transformation $D_{Qa} : \mathbb R^{n \times m} \to \mathbb R^n, D_{Qa}(H) = Ha$ which is what the derivative of $Qa$ should be.

Comment: I don't get your answer. By the way, I referred to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649156/how-to-define-the-derivative-of-a-vector-wrt-to-a-matrix

Comment: I am using the definition of a general derivative. The derivative of $f : X \to Y$ at some $x$ where $X, Y$ are Banach spaces is the linear transformation $Df_x : X \to Y$ s.t. $$\lim_{\|h\| \to 0} \frac{ \|f(x + h) - f(x) - Df_x(h) \| }{\| h \|}$$ Also according to the link you gave it should be $a \otimes I_n$ not $a \otimes I_m$ they were using $m \times n$ matrices not $n \times m$ like yours

Comment: Ok, but the result should be the one I pointed out as correctly computed in the other question I posted (EDIT: correct, I fixed it). Btw, regardless of the derivative of that term, any idea on how to compute the derivative of $QQ^{\top}\mathbb{1}$ with respect to $Q$?

Comment: The answer in the link can be made to be in concordance with the true definition of derivative. You can express $D_{Qa}(H) = Ha = (a \otimes I_n)^T \text{vec}(H)$. So if you are willing to view a matrix $H$ as its vectorized form, $D_{Qa}$ is essentially like $a \otimes I_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v : \mathbb R^{n \times m} \to \mathbb R^n$ be our quadratic term $v(Q) = QQ^{\intercal}1$. We compute the difference:
$$
v(Q + H) - v(Q) = (Q + H)(Q + H)^{\intercal}1 - QQ^{\intercal}1 = (QH^{\intercal}1 + HQ^{\intercal}1) + HH^{\intercal}1
$$ It is not hard to show that the derivative of $v$ at some $Q$ is the linear transformation
$$
Dv_Q(H) = QH^{\intercal}1 + HQ^{\intercal}1
$$ Using the identity
$
\text{vec}(XYZ) = (Z^{\intercal} \otimes X)\text{vec}(Y)
$ on both summands above we see that
\begin{align*}
Dv_Q(H) &= (1^\intercal \otimes Q)\text{vec}(H^\intercal) + (1^\intercal Q \otimes I_n)\text{vec}(H) \\
&= \Big[(1^\intercal \otimes Q)K^{(n,m)} + (1^\intercal Q \otimes I_n)\Big]\text{vec}(H)
\end{align*} where $K^{(n, m)}$ is the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) that transforms $\text{vec}(H)$ to $\text{vec}(H^\intercal)$.

Thus through the isomorphism $\text{vec} : \mathbb R^{n \times m} \cong \mathbb R^{nm}$ you can think of $\frac{dv}{dQ}$ as the matrix
$$
(1^\intercal \otimes Q)K^{(n,m)} + (1^\intercal Q \otimes I_n)
$$ So as a whole you can think of the derivative of the original function $\frac{du}{dQ}$ as
$$
(a^\intercal \otimes I_n) - (1^\intercal \otimes Q)K^{(n,m)} - (1^\intercal Q \otimes I_n)
$$ If you want to be in concordance with the post that motivated this question in the first place, you can simply transpose the above.